# Manga on martial arts in a Fantasy world with humanoid beasts

Tags: story-identification, manga

I am looking for a manga I read a few years ago (~4-5 years), and I can't remember the name of it or find it. It's not a famous manga, I'm not even sure if it's a Japanese comic, maybe Chinese or Korean, and it's uncompleted.

It's a story in a medieval Asian fantasy world, about fights and martial arts. In this world, I remember that humanoid beasts cohabit with humans, there are rabbit fighters, an archer goat, and things like that. I think the main characters are a daddy and his daughter who are travelling, and he teaches her martial arts.

Comment: When you said a few years ago do you know roughly how many? If so you could [edit] that into your post. You may also want to check out our [useful guide](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/58193) on what to include and also the [specific anime/manga one](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/11875/58193). However, this is a good description so far, maybe add some plot elements if you remember any, and this is certainly a fine place to ask this question!

Comment: Were the father and/or daughter human or humanoid beasts? Can the humans interbreeed with the humanoid beasts? Can the beasts breed between species? Do you remember what sort of weapons the father and his daughter use?

Comment: Is this colored or not ?

Answer (score -1):

Sounds like its the manhwa called **Dosa** , which is the prequel to the manhwa called **White Epic**

Comment: Could you [edit] this to explain how it matches the OP’s description?